# Server gives error 500 on a loop with sleep - php

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am getting internal server error with a loop in php.

The loop basically do this:

```
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) { 
   sleep(5); 
  }
```

it have an execution time limit set to 120 and also set the memory limit and display erros.

```
set_time_limit(120);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');
```

I get an 500 internal server error.

And other script in the same server stop to work while looping.

Comment: Are you getting any other errors/warnings in your PHP error log? I've just tested it locally and it's working as expected.

Comment: Why are you sleeping like that, out of curiosity?

Comment: minitech: that loop is just an example. It actually do a lot more, but I cant show you. Basically it checks for another method response periodically and after X amount of time it stops

Comment: If you're running PHP as CGI, which is the default for IIS, there is a separate timer within your HTTP server which dictates how long it will wait before throwing an HTTP 500. Check into that.

Comment: Same as @Sammitch for Apache on win32 -- verify that you aren't hitting alternative limits that cause the 500.

Comment: try 64M to see if it works as 128M might be over memory limit. but debug try time limit then memory limit to see which one gives error.

Comment: I have tryied locally I set the memory as down as 4m and works fine. But when i set the time limit to 30 it gives an error. Wich is fine becouse the script runs for 36 seconds.

I think the problem may be in the server config.

Answer (score 0):

There is another Runtime Configuration In 
You must change value of 
**max_execution_time** In php.ini
usually this attribute set to 30 seconds , you can increase this to 100 seconds